# Access Ipython Notebook Running on Remote Server

Tags: python, linux, ssh, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Have installed Anaconda Python on remote linux machine.

Used **putty** on local Windows to login to remote linux machine to remotely start the Ipython Notebook. It's started on port 8888.

**remote_user**@remote_host$ ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8888

Now I need to access this Notebook on local browser. 
Have tried doing ssh tunnel.

C:\Users\**windowsUser**> ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8888 remote_user@remote_host

**ssh: connect to host remote_host port 22: Bad file number**

But not able to get it right. Getting the above error

Note: the user **windowsUser** does not exist on remote_host(linux). Remote user account is remote_user.

Where am i going wrong?
Plzz help

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a typo. In your ssh command you should not have "localhost" twice.

The corrected command is:

```
ssh -N -f -L 8888:localhost:8888 remote_user@remote_host
```

Because the syntax for the command is:

```
ssh -L <Local Port>:<Local Machine>:<Target Port>  <Target Machine>
```

(see http://www.slashroot.in/ssh-port-forwarding-linux-configuration-and-examples)

Furthermore, you could instead modify your ssh config file (in `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh_config`) to include port forwarding:

```
Host remote_host
Hostname PUT_REMOTE_IP_HERE
Port 22
User remote_user
LocalForward 8888 localhost:8888
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think window has a ssh cmd,

if local is a standard ssh client use

`C:\Users\windowsUser> ssh -N -f -L 8888:localhost:8888 remote_user@remote_host`

#### BTW

`ipython notebook --ip=remote_host_ip`

then you can access with http://remote_host_ip:8888/tree